# There is an instrument similar to Meowsic Cat Piano, but with Chicken sounds?

Tags: software, instruments, keyboard, midi, synthesizer

I'm working on a game with chickens and I would love to have the chickens sing songs, pretty similar to Gonzo Chickens from "Muppets show".
But I'm having a hard time finding a way to do it.

I found this cat keyboard that does something similar to what I want, however it produces cat meow sounds.

Any tips on this? 
If there is not an instrument, is there any way to accomplish this with software?  Maybe with a midi keyboard? Or another way to get the effect?

Comment: (to voters-to-close) I don't know, guys. I think this would be off-topic, except that OP clearly satisfies "Describe the required setting and function [...] ask what you should look for to achieve that".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a video](https://youtu.be/3I1pEbiYSCw) talking about the more general case of the problem you want to solve.

In it, Neely explores a few (rather extreme) ways that historically the problem has been solved in the past, even mentioning the very product you mention in your question, if I'm not mistaken. I believe one trivial solution he mentions is literally to assemble a chicken-abusing apparatus to make noise, which has got to be the funniest idea I've ever heard of for a musical instrument.

Comment: So I need to find and torture some chickens, that happens to have the right pitches. That's the right answer to the question, for sure! lol

Comment: @RinaldoBueno Maybe you could train your chickens to produce the right note every time or something! (can chickens have perfect pitch? and other absurd musical studies) :)

Comment: Don't stop there. There's the sequels - 'In the Moood' with cows, and of course anything by Bark 'sung' by dogs. And the Neighbours theme done by horses, and I'm sure 'Flight of the Bumble Bee could be adapted...

Answer (score 2):

That cat keyboard doesn't really make the most realistic cats sounds. And the muppets were just people making chicken sounds.

So you could record 5 or 6 (or more if needed) chicken sounds with your voice and then map those samples with a sampler.

There is lots of info about this on the internet. That's how I'd approach this.

Comment: Could you please refer a good reference? It seems that I'm having a hard time to find the right key words...

Comment: What software do you have?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>No, this is not a serious answer. Please don't treat it as one ;)</sup>

Cue obvious YouTube link...

Ray Stevens - In The Mood

& The live cover...

Carol Burnett

Comment: Yeah, you got the idea. That's pretty much what I want to achieve. but it can have like less quality, since the idea is to have midi files played with chickens sounds